# Add Serilog LogContext to every log call

Tags: .net-6.0, serilog

Is there a way to "inject" LogContext call to all the Serilog log calls in a project?
I'd like to add an ExecutionContext property, which is just a hex string generated in a shared class library.
I'm using Serilog with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, and also using Serilog Request Logging in Asp.Net Core API project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can implement `ILogEventEnricher` Interface to do that  like
this event will fires on every log  event an  in application.

```
public class PropertyBagEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
    {
       
        public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
        {
           logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(propertyFactory.CreateProperty(your key, your Value));
            }
        }
```